# Spring annotations, read properties

Tags: java, spring-annotations

I have small test project to test Spring annotations:

[image]

where in `nejake.properties` is:

```
klucik = hodnoticka
```

and in `App.java` is:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/com/ektyn/springProperties/nejake.properties")
public class App
{
    @Value("${klucik}")
    private String klc;



    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx1 = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        ctx1.register(App.class);
        ctx1.refresh();
        //
        App app = new App();
        app.printIt();
    }



    private void printIt()
    {
        System.out.println(klc);
    }
}
```

It should print `hodnoticka` on console, but prints `null` - String value is not initialized. My code is bad - at the moment I have no experience with annotation driven Spring. What's bad with code above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created the object yourself

```
App app = new App();
app.printIt();
```

how is Spring supposed to manage the instance and inject the value?

You will however need

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

to make the properties available. Also, because the `App` bean initialized for handling `@Configuration` is initialized before the resolver for `@Value`, the value field will not have been set. Instead, declare a different `App` bean and retrieve it

```
@Bean
public App appBean() {
    return new App();
}
...
App app = (App) ctx1.getBean("appBean");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the property from a Spring bean, and you need to properly wire in the properties. First, add to your config class this:

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceHolderConfigurer() {

    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer props = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    props.setLocations(new Resource[] { new ClassPathResource("com/ektyn/springProperties/nejake.properties") }); //I think that's its absolute location, but you may need to play around with it to make sure
    return props;
}
```

Then you need to access them from within a Spring Bean. Typically, your config file should not be a bean, so I would recommend you make a separate class, something like this:

```
@Component //this makes it a spring bean
public class PropertiesAccessor {

   @Value("${klucik}")
    private String klc;

    public void printIt() {
        System.out.println(klc);
    }
}
```

Finally, add this to your config to make it find the `PropertiesAccessor`:

`@ComponentScan("com.ektyn.springProperties")`

Then you can access the `PropertiesAccessor` bean from your app context and call its `printIt` method.